# wpColorPicker: How update colors on input value update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, color-picker

**Setup:**

- An input field that has attached a `wpColorPicker` instance.
- An external event that changes the input value color.

**Issues:**

- On value change the color shown by the colorpicker doesn't get automatically updated, neither the selection when user open up the colorpicker dialog box.
- `wpColorPicker` doesn't have neither`remove`, `destroy` nor `update` methods, so there is no simple way to do this.
- And lastly, they wrap the input field in a bunch of other tags to do the styling, so no simple manual removal can be done.

**Question:**

- How can I update the color on the widget and its selection when user initiates interaction upon field value change?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by looking into the inner `.iris()` and check that it has a `.('color')` method that allows to set a color at runtime.

Thankfully, this `.('color')` method is supported too by `.wpColorPicker()`, so one can do:

```
var new_color = $the_related_field.val();
$the_colorpicker.wpColorpicker('color', new_color);
```

to overcome the annoyance of not having an `update()` method.